# Overloaded method calls redesign

Tags: java

I have an interface `IAction` that has one generic method:

```
public interface IAction  {
    void doAction(ISignal sig, IState state);
}
```

Another class `IActionAbstract` then implements the `IAction` interface and calls overloaded methods with `instanceof` clauses:

```
public abstract class IActionAbstract implements IAction
{

@Override
public void doAction(ISignal sig, IState state)
{
    if(sig instanceof ISignal1 && state instanceof IState1)
    {
        doOther((ISignal1)sig, (IState1)state);
    }       
    else if(sig instanceof ISignal2 && state instanceof IState1)
    {
        doOther((ISignal2)sig, (IState1)state);
    }
    else if(sig instanceof ISignal1 && state instanceof IState2)
    {
        doOther((ISignal1)sig, (IState2)state);
    }
}

abstract void doOther(ISignal1 sig, IState1 state);
abstract void doOther(ISignal2 sig, IState1 state);
abstract void doOther(ISignal1 sig, IState2 state);
}
```

I would like to remove the `instanceof` checks and replace with generics or redesign, but without adding more methods to `IAction`.  I see how to do this with reflection, but would like to avoid if possible.

Edit: Removed generics since they are not required.  I will try and explain more to give a better idea of this approach.  The `IActionAbstract` file might be generated with the developer making an impl to implement the methods.  `ISignal` and `IState` together make the method unique and can be thought of as a state machine state and signal.

Usage of the classes would look like in pseudo-code:

```
List<IAction> actions;
actions.get(i).doAction(ISignal1, IState1);
actions.get(i).doAction(ISignal2, IState2);
and so on...
```

Comment: Could you elaborate the pseudo-code in the end - where do the different signals and states come from? Also, please provide the ISignal and IState interfaces, and possibly some sample implementations of what the doOther methods do.

Comment: I ended up using reflection due to my unique situation with the needs for some generated and some not, claesv thanks for the help in confirming my options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you want separate implementations of IAction, i.e.

```
// generic interface declaration
public interface IAction<T extends ISignal, S extends IState> {
    void doAction(T sig, S state);
}

// typed implementations of the generic interface
public class Action1 implements IAction<Signal1, State1> {
    doAction(Signal1 sig, State1 state) {
        // impl
    }
}

// another typed implementations of the generic interface
public class Action2 implements IAction<Signal2, State2> {
    doAction(Signal2 sig, State2 state) {
        // impl
    }
}
```

...and so on. Otherwise you're not even using generics.

Comment: The Encapsulation of the methods in one object is important.  You are right about generics, I was more alluding to using them if Java allowed multiple inheritance, generics didn't have type erasure, or there was a pattern I am missing.

Comment: Maybe you could update your question to 1) not use generics if you're not going to use them, 2) include some more info on which types of Actions Signals and States you're working with, and how they typically interact. The code you have know looks conceptually weird, and maybe a different approach altogether is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I updated to hopefully make the question more clear.  Though I am not sure I understand what you are asking for exactly in 2).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. I agree with @claesv that your approach probably isn't necessary. Here is my approach:

```
public class GenericsQuestion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ISignal sig = new Signal1();
        IState state = new State1();

        Strategy.getStrategyForSignalAndState(sig.getClass(), state.getClass()).doOther(sig, state);
    }
}

class SignalAndState {
    private Class<? extends IState> state;
    private Class<? extends ISignal> signal;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public SignalAndState(Class<? extends ISignal> signal, Class<? extends IState> state2) {
        // save state and signal
    }
    // equals & hashcode
}

enum Strategy {
    ONE {
        @Override
        public void doOther(ISignal sig, IState state) {
        }
    },
    TWO {
        @Override
        public void doOther(ISignal sig, IState state) {
        }
    },
    THREE {
        @Override
        public void doOther(ISignal sig, IState state) {
        }
    };

    private static final Map<SignalAndState, Strategy> STRATEGIES = new HashMap<SignalAndState, Strategy>();
    static {
        STRATEGIES.put(new SignalAndState(Signal1.class, State1.class), ONE);
        STRATEGIES.put(new SignalAndState(Signal1.class, State2.class), TWO);
        STRATEGIES.put(new SignalAndState(Signal2.class, State1.class), THREE);
    }

    public static Strategy getStrategyForSignalAndState(Class<? extends ISignal> sig, Class<? extends IState> state) {
        return STRATEGIES.get(new SignalAndState(sig, state));
    }

    public abstract void doOther(ISignal sig, IState state);
}
```

I my eyes, this would be more elegant and flexible than using instanceof.

You could probably improve this by using EnumMap, but I don't use that much and am unsure about the benefits and/or usage. Just a hint if you'd like to investigate further.