# Call method once after any one of a few overloaded methods are called

Tags: java, generics, overloading

In an abstract class I have a `Predicate` field, that is meant to be a combination of an unknown number of other `Predicate`s. Joining the predicates works just fine but I am trying to have some way to know when the predicate has been initialized (or rather, just a way to know if it has or hasn't been initted).

Here is a short example of what I'm talking about:

```
public abstract class LimitedSystem implements Moveable {

private Predicate<Double> limits;
private final boolean initialized;

public void setLimits(SingleLimit... limits) {

    List<Predicate<Double>> limitsList = Arrays.asList(limits);
    this.limits = limitsList.stream().reduce(Predicate::and).orElse(x -> true);
}

public void setLimits(TwoLimits limits) {
    this.limits = limits;
}
...
```

I am looking for ways to set `initialized` to `true` once (and once only, hence the `final`. I think I used it right) any of the `setLimits` have been called (they're overloaded).

I have other `setLimits` methods, but for the sake of generic code, I don't want to put a `initialized` at the end of each of the overloaded methods.

So my question is how can I, in a generic way, set the value of `initialized` after any of the `setLimits` methods has been called.

My first idea was to try to wrap the `setLimits` in some generic method which would call the correct overload by the parameter it gets, and then change `initialized` in that method. But I am not sure if that's a good idea.

Some other idea I got from another question<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310564/overloaded-method-calls-redesign)</sup> was to put the `setLimits` in some interface or something similar. But I'm not sure how useful that might prove.

So how might this be accomplished?

(Also, if you happen to notice any design problems in this, please tell me because I'm trying to improve in that matter)

Comment: How about replacing setLimits with constructors?

Comment: I'd like to remind you that final fields have to be set in the declaration line or in the constructor. So you can't assign their value in a random method. I know it's not the real question.

Comment: @Törpetestű oh. Didn't know that either. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for separate fields:

```
private Predicate<Double> limits;
private final boolean initialized;
```

is basically

```
private Optional<Predicate<Double>> limits = Optional.empty();
```

if you want `initialized` to be set to `true` once `limits` is set, 
provided you can guarantee that none of the `setLimits` methods can set it to `Optional.empty()` again. `initialized == limits.isPresent()`.

---

You can't guarantee that a method is called in the body of an overridden method; in any case, this is a variant of the [Call super antipattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_super).

You can do it like this:

```
abstract class Base {
  final void setFoo(Object param) {  // final, so can't be overridden.
    setFooImpl(param);
    thingThatMustBeCalled();
  }

  protected abstract void setFooImpl(Object param);

  final void thingThatMustBeCalled() { ... }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  @Override protected void setFooImpl(Object param) { ... }
}
```

But it's pretty ugly.

Comment: I didn't know `Optional` works this way. I'll try this now.

Comment: So this eliminates the need for calling a method after any overloaded one was called. Hmph, still wondering if that's possible. but that's a different question than this, so I might ask another (more general and yet a bit more specific) question soon. (in a different post, naturally)

Comment: Ah. That doesn't look neat. I'll stick to the `Optional`. Thanks anyway :D